# Ubuntu becomes quite laggy after wake up

Tags: suspend

I'm running Ubuntu 15.04 on my UX32A Zenbook Prime with Intel® Core™ i5-3317U CPU @ 1.70GHz × 4 processor and Intel® Ivybridge Mobile Graphics.

When I wake up my computer from sleep mode, I find it becomes quite laggy. Slow response times and lots of freezing existing pages already open. Opening new pages becomes a nightmare and I just restart my computer thereafter. Does anybody know what I can do to solve this?

Comment: Run dmesg after the comp is awakened and see if there's any useful information there.

Comment: I haven't run it yet, because im preparing for an interview and need my laptop desperately atm, but running  `dmesg` returns a lot of information, what are we looking for?

Comment: I don't know exactly since I don't know what applications are installed on your laptop but if you run it right after waking the PC there might be some information about some apps trying to do some funky stuff. 

I helped my friend with his mac taking too long to wake up, dmesg showed us that google chrome did a lot of things (can't remember exactly what) just before the mac woke up.

Comment: There's all sorts of information, would you like me to copy paste it all? Sorry I've been away from this question

Comment: I suppose I can take a look. Why don't you copy/paste the last 100 lines into a pastebin and paste the link to it here?

Answer (score 6):

It could be the `msr register 0x19a` is not set back to 0 after resume. Try to set it to 0 by installing `msr-tools` and run `wrmsr 0x19a 0x0`.

It fixes for me.

Comment: I am looking for examples such as yours, where Clock Modulation is enabled after resume from suspend. Does it always happen for you, or just when resuming on battery? What Computer type and model number? When you read register 0x19a what do you get? And does that make sense for what frequency your CPUs run at? Does the register still have bit 4 set upon resume from suspend when you are running the acpi-cpufreq frequency scaling driver?

Comment: Would vote you up twice for an explanation of why this fixes it. Also fixed it for me.

Comment: To be clear, I should run this after resume when I am having the problem?

Comment: If you get an error about an open operation, run `sudo modprobe msr`.

Comment: I get: `wrmsr: pwrite: Operation not permitted`

Comment: I tried the same thing. I get `wrmsr: CPU 0 cannot set MSR 0x0000019a to 0x0000000000000000`

Any ideas?