# Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS too slow after suspend and resume

Tags: 16.04, lts

I recently updated Ubuntu to this version because it asked for it and when I wake up my computer from suspend everything is super slow, the mouse barely moves and jumps at times so I basically have to restart the PC. I'm using an intel i5 in a lenovo desktop.

The msr trick ([Ubuntu becomes quite laggy after wake up](https://askubuntu.com/questions/623149/ubuntu-becomes-quite-laggy-after-wake-up)) doesn't have effect.

Did someone  manage to fix this issue? I've seen this question asked often:

```
https://askubuntu.com/questions/623149/ubuntu-becomes-quite-laggy-after-wake-up
https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=199922
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1985755
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/892544
```

Comment: Could you [edit] your post to make it clear exactly what "msr trick" and "doesn't work" means in your particular case? A review of http://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask should help you determine how to write a useful question and improve your odds of getting a useful answer. Thank you for helping us help you!

Comment: Been happening to me lately too. Also nic driver doesn't resume and needs `rmmod` followed by `insmod`. Might be related to older systemd-shim bug I was reading about couple of days ago because my system does a double suspend as per `/var/log/syslog` but I haven't completed research on thus low priority issue yet.

Comment: I have MSR set in grub too I think (on phone now) but that might have been for clock speed and `thermald`